# Inflation of effect size estimation among significant results?

Tags: estimation, multiple-comparisons, effect-size, regularization, publication-bias

Correction for multiple testing is often performed on the alpha value. However, multiple testing is, I think, likely to inflate also the estimated effect size of the most significant effects found.

Consider for example a case where we investigate the effect of one independent variable on 50 dependent variables with 50 independent tests. We will assume that the independent variable has an effect size of say $E≠0$ on all 50 dependent variables. We perform a Bonferroni correction and we end up finding some significant effects. The mean effect size for the significant results will be clearly greater than $E$.

Is there any way we could account for this inflation of the effect size among significant results? Should I consider that effect sizes are generally overestimated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Gelman [has blogged on the topic](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2011/09/10/the-statistical-significance-filter/).  Is there some answer? Maybe some form of regularization or *shrinking* can be used. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5133138/) is a sample paper that looks interesting.

How can this occur?  If you use an unbiased estimator of some effect of interest, but only publish results if they are significant, then the published estimates will tend to be to large. And the maximum of many estimated effects of approximately same size, will tend to be to large.  This is a large and broad topic, and to say much more we need a more concrete question.

One way to investigate this is the [funnel plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel_plot), see the posts https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=funnel+plot++answers%3A1